# Specify external library PATH on Run with QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have included an external library on my Qt project on Windows.
The build process works perfectly but when I try to run the code, it fails.

I know that the reason of the fail is that the linked library DLLs paths are not included in the PATH ambient variable/they are not in the executable path.

One solution can be to add the DLLs paths into the PATH ambient variable or copy the DLLs in the execution path but I want to avoid these and find an automated solution.

I know that is possible to add an INSTALL command into the .pro file so, if I add to the build sequence the command `make install`, the dependencies specified will be copied into the execution path. Can someone give me an example? The code that i use for include the library is the follow:

```
message(Importing SAT-Sdk)
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../SDK/dist/SAT-Sdk/lib/ -lsat_sdk
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../SDK/dist/SAT-Sdk/lib/ -lsat_sdkd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../SDK/dist/SAT-Sdk/lib/ -lsat_sdk

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../SDK/dist/SAT-Sdk/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../SDK/dist/SAT-Sdk/include
```

Another solution can be to specify the path of the DLLs adding a command into the pre-configured run settings but I don't know the exact syntax. Can anyone give me an example?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add files to `install` target as described in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#installing-files.  You can probably simply add something like this:

```
target.files += $$PWD/../../../SDK/dist/SAT-Sdk/lib/sat_sdk.dll
```

Though the lib file name may depend on the target platform and debug/release build on Windows (with w/out "d" suffix). Personally I set all this in some central location somewhere so I don't need to duplicate all those paths and such.  Example below (not tested, YMMV, there are many ways to do this... etc :)

```
SAT_SDK_PATH = $$PWD/../../../SDK/dist/SAT-Sdk
SAT_SDK_LIB_PATH = $$SAT_SDK_PATH/lib
SAT_SDK_LIB = sat_sdk
win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release):SAT_SDK_LIB = $${SAT_SDK_LIB}d

win32:SAT_SDK_LIB_BIN = $${SAT_SDK_LIB}.dll
else:SAT_SDK_LIB_BIN = lib$${SAT_SDK_LIB}.$${QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB}

LIBS += -L$$SAT_SDK_LIB_PATH -l$$SAT_SDK_LIB
INCLUDEPATH += $SAT_SDK_PATH/include
DEPENDPATH += $SAT_SDK_PATH/include

target.files += $$SAT_SDK_LIB_PATH/$$SAT_SDK_LIB_BIN
target.path = #install path ...

!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is what I was searching for

Answer (score 1):

You can set the PATH environment variable in your projects' Build Environment or Run Environment. As an example, see [this project](https://sourceforge.net/p/vmpk/wiki/develop/).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I wait if someone knows a different solution using the INSTALL command